# Im trying to have a button do one action at once in two cells, getting error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently working on an excel doc for work, and on it has two cells that have the same value in two different spots so it lines up in our system. This is what I currently have.

```
Sub CheckDuplicateVALUE()

'Declaring variables
Dim Cell As Variant
Dim Source As Range

'Initializing source range
Set Source = Range("O4:O200,C4:C200")

'Removing any previous formatting from the source
Source.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)

'Looping through each cell in the source range
For Each Cell In Source
    
    'Checking whether value in cell already exist in the source range
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Source, Cell) > 1 Then
        
        'Highlighting duplicate values in red color
        Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

What do I need to change in order to have it work in cells O4:O200 and C4:C200. I did not make this code I found it online as I just need help creating some things.

Comment: I don't think you can use `CountIf` with a non-contiguous range. What exactly is the end goal here?

Comment: To highlight any duplicated value in those cell values. I have two buttons one for each of the value ranges, but I need them to be highlighted at the same time so whoever uses it knows to change both values to be the same.

Comment: Are you comparing duplicates across the two ranges? So for example, `C4` = "foo" and `O4` = "foo", both would be highlighted?

Comment: Im comparing duplicates in the entire cell range like C4 = foo and C5 = foo. So when I run it it would highlight it and I can change it. But the range O4:O200 are the exact same values from C4:C200 only because we need to upload the files into a system and they need to match an exact format. So basically C4 needs to equal O4. and C4 can't be equal to lets say C5 and O5.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` doesn't work with a multi-area range as the first argument.

---

> I'm comparing duplicates in the entire cell range like C4 = foo and C5 = foo. So when I run it it would highlight it and I can change it.

In that case, refactor to something like the following, calling `HighlightDupes` twice, once on each range.

```
Private Sub HighlightDupes(ByVal source As Range)
    source.Interior.Color = vbWhite

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In source
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(source, cell.Value) > 1 Then
            cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Sub CheckDuplicateVALUE()
    HighlightDupes Range("O4:O400")
    HighlightDupes Range("C4:C400")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you just use conditional formatting on each range? It has a duplicate values function. I just recorded a macro and threw it into a simple loop in case you want to automate it. The code is ugly, but it should work fine for your circumstances.

```
Sub check_duplicates()

    Dim form_rng As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    Set ws = Workbooks("your workbook").Sheets("your sheet")
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    For i = 1 To 2
        If i = 1 Then
            Set form_rng = ws.Range("C4:C400")
        Else
            Set form_rng = ws.Range("O4:O400")
        End If
        form_rng.Select
        Selection.FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
        Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        Selection.FormatConditions(1).DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
        With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
            .Color = -16383844
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 13551615
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Next i


End Sub
```